# How to cancel an `async` function with cancellable type returned from `async` operation initiation

Tags: swift, async-await, cancellation

I need to support cancellation of a function that returns an object that can be cancelled after initiation. In my case, the `requester` class is in a 3rd party library that I can't modify.

```
actor MyActor {

    ...

    func doSomething() async throws -> ResultData {

        var requestHandle: Handle?
    
        return try await withTaskCancellationHandler {
            requestHandle?.cancel() // COMPILE ERROR: "Reference to captured var 'requestHandle' in concurrently-executing code"
        } operation: {

            return try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation{ continuation in
            
                requestHandle = requester.start() { result, error in
            
                    if let error = error
                        continuation.resume(throwing: error)
                    } else {
                        let myResultData = ResultData(result)
                        continuation.resume(returning: myResultData)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

I have reviewed other SO questions and this thread: https://forums.swift.org/t/how-to-use-withtaskcancellationhandler-properly/54341/4

There are cases that are very similar, but not quite the same. This code won't compile because of this error:

> "Reference to captured var 'requestHandle' in concurrently-executing code"

I assume the compiler is trying to protect me from using the `requestHandle` before it's initialized. But I'm not sure how else to work around this problem. The other examples shown in the Swift Forum discussion thread all seem to have a pattern where the `requester` object can be initialized before calling its `start` function.

I also tried to save the `requestHandle` as a class variable, but I got a different compile error at the same location:

> Actor-isolated property 'profileHandle' can not be referenced from a
> Sendable closure

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You said:

> I assume the compiler is trying to protect me from using the `requestHandle` before it’s initialized.

Or, more accurately, it is simply protecting you against a race. You need to synchronize your interaction with your “requester” and that `Handle`.

> But I’m not sure how else to work around this problem. The other examples shown in the Swift Forum discussion thread all seem to have a pattern where the `requester` object can be initialized before calling its `start` function.

Yes, that is precisely what you should do. Unfortunately, you haven’t shared where your `requester` is being initialized or how it was implemented, so it is hard for us to comment on your particular situation.

But the fundamental issue is that you need to synchronize your `start` and `cancel`. So if your `requester` doesn’t already do that, you should wrap it in an object that provides that thread-safe interaction. The standard way to do that in Swift concurrency is with an actor.

---

For example, let us imagine that you are wrapping a network request. To synchronize your access with this, you can create an actor:

```swift
actor ResponseDataRequest {
    private var handle: Handle?

    func start(completion: @Sendable @escaping (Data?, Error?) -> Void) {
        // start it and save handle for cancelation, e.g.,
        
        handle = requestor.start(...)
    }

    func cancel() {
        handle?.cancel()
    }
}
```

That wraps the starting and canceling of a network request in an actor. Then you can do things like:

```swift
func doSomething() async throws -> ResultData {
    let responseDataRequest = ResponseDataRequest()

    return try await withTaskCancellationHandler {
        Task { await responseDataRequest.cancel() }
    } operation: {
        return try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
            Task {
                await responseDataRequest.start { result, error in
                    if let error = error {
                        continuation.resume(throwing: error)
                    } else {
                        let resultData = ResultData(result)
                        continuation.resume(returning: resultData)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You obviously can shift to unsafe continuations when you have verified that everything is working with your checked continuations.

Comment: I failed to mention in question that the `doSomething` function was already in an `actor` where I tried to do something similar to what you suggested (I updated question). But it looks like wrapping the cancellation handle block with `Task{ await requestHandle?.cancel() }` is the key here. Btw, if I remove the `Task` wrapper in the body of the `withCheckedThrowingContinuation` closure, it compiles cleanly as well - so not sure if this is essential to your fix? Have yet to test this actually supports cancellation or survives stress testing. Not even sure how to write a unit test for this.

Comment: Correct. The `Task` wrapper in `withCheckedThrowingContinuation` body is only needed if one introduces that separate local actor variable to synchronize the cancelation handler.

Answer (score -1):

After reviewing the Swift discussion thread again, I see you can do this:

```
...
var requestHandle: Handle?

let onCancel = { profileHandle?.cancel() }

return try await withTaskCancellationHandler {
    onCancel()
}
...
```

Comment: I would be wary of using this `onCancel` closure pattern. It actually hides the underlying problem and in Swift 6 this will start generating errors. E.g. try adding the "Other Swift Flags" build settings of `-Xfrontend -warn-concurrency -Xfrontend -enable-actor-data-race-checks`.